# Separete jvm options for each different applications in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

Hi Is it possible set jvm options for different applications in tomcat.I set jvm option but it effects all war files in tomcat.How can I separete.I have a spring boot application and normally I can start my spring
like

```
java -jar -Dspring.profile.active=dev
```

But now on I change my package type to war and deploy them to tomcat and each war is different spring application so I need to separe their jvm options

In tomcat ,the applications like

```
myrestservice1-->jvm options -Dspring.profile.active=dev
myrestservice2-->jvm options -Dspring.profile.active=test
```

I use tomcat 9

Answer (score 1):

You'll do this by starting each application on a separate Tomcat. They're all sharing the same JVM by default, when running in the same server.

There is no configuration option to behave differently, unless you run tomcat in separate processes/JVMs in the first place.

There you're free to provide as many configuration values to each process/JVM/tomcat as you like.

You *might* be able to provide spring configuration in a different way, but that's not what you are asking for (and *I* couldn't tell you anyway).

Comment: seperate tomcat mean virtual hosts in tomcat or completely seperate tomcat?

Comment: Separate Tomcat. _Every_ single Tomcat you start, runs in its own JVM. _Nothing_ in Tomcat separates by JVM or starts a separate one. You determine the number of JVMs running by starting them explicitly as separate processes (tomcats).